# API key working on localhost, but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an app that uses the Google Maps API and Meetup.com's API to load events onto the map. My API key for Meetup is stored and exported at the bottom of my .zshrc file, and it works fine on localhost. But the API returns a 500 when I attempt to use the app on Heroku.

Here's my meetup.js controller:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

function getEvents(req, res) {

  request.get({
    url: "https://api.meetup.com/2/open_events",
    qs: {
      key: process.env.MEETUP_API_KEY,
      lat: req.query.lat,
      lon: req.query.lng,
      category: req.query.category,
      radius: req.query.radius || 1,
      sign: true
    },
    json: true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    res.status(200).json(response.results);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  })
}

function getCategories(req, res) {

  request.get({
    url: "https://api.meetup.com/2/categories",
    qs: {
      key: process.env.MEETUP_API_KEY,
      sign: true
    },
    json: true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    res.status(200).json(response.results);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getEvents: getEvents,
  getCategories: getCategories
}
```

And my dependencies in the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation": "^5.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "request": "^2.74.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Heroku didn't have a value assigned for the API key, so in the working directory, the value can be assigned with

```
heroku config add:MEETUP_API_KEY="[key value here]"
```